# Is there a workflow where projects are source controlled when working with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, project, projects-and-solutions, solution

Assume I have a solution called "My Program", a project under it called "My Program Lib" and a second project called "My Program Client".

Does Visual Studio support a workflow where I can check "My Program Lib" into source control separately to the solution "My Program"?

This is so that "My Program Lib" can be used in other solutions like "My Web Program" for example.

Comment: it's often better for one's sanity to share the projects compiled binary output rather than the project....

Answer (score 0):

Define "support".

You have a couple of options:

- Put "My Program Lib" into a separate Visual Studio project and reference it from the projects that will use it. This implies/requires that you have a certain directory structure in the projects and you can't just move projects around once you've set them up. Plus, you're sharing the source so you'll end up rebuilding all the projects that depend on your library every time the library changes.
- Package it up into a package you can depend on from your other projects, using something like NuGet and a repository of your own. This might be a overkill in your case, though. This would allow you to share the compiled output as Mitch suggested, but it's more work initially.

Comment: NuGet doesn't support a kind of source-distribution, does it?

Comment: I believe there is a way to do that, but I'm anything but an expert on NuGet.